# Convertir word a pdf en c#

Tags: c#

estoy utilizando el siguiente código para hacer la conversión de archivos word a pdf:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        word.Visible = false;
        word.ScreenUpdating = false;

        FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo("C:\\documento.docx");
        Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        doc.Activate();

        object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

        // Save document into PDF Format
        doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
            ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
          
        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        doc = null;


        ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        word = null;
```

El problema es que el archivo que genera sale en formato ".pdfx", ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me genere un archivo ".pdf"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero aclaremos un tema, por lo que observo en tu código, lo que te esta sucediendo,. es que estas guardando tu archivo con extensión `.pdfx` cuando debió ser `.pdf`, pero eso no significa que lo hayas creado con formato `.pdfx`, la linea de código siguiente: `object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;` garantiza que tu archivo sea convertido a formato `pdf` lo cual no tiene que ver con que el nombre que le has colocado no sea el correcto.

En la siguiente linea solo reemplazas `".doc"` por `".pdf"`

```
object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
```

si haces eso y tu archivo es de `FullName ="C:\\documento.docx"` el valor de `outputFileName` que devolverá esa linea anterior será `"C:\\documento.pdfx"` pues solo has mandado a reemplazar la cadena `.doc` por `.pdf`el resto de la cadena, tanto lo que le antecede como lo que le sucede se mantendrá inalterable, si quieres lograr que quede como `"C:\\documento.pdf"` la linea tendrás que sustituirla por lo siguiente.

```
  object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
```

La respuesta de RobertoLeOr es también valida y tal ves mas elegante, solo te incluyo esta respuesta como ejemplo de que las cosas que nos suceden a veces son por que hacemos una errónea interpretación de lo que hacen las funciones que usamos, la función `Replace` sustituye la cadena que especificamos en el primer argumento por la cadena que especificamos en el segundo argumento, el resto de la cadena se mantiene inalterable, así que si es `.docx` lo que quieres reemplazar y solo mandaste a reemplazar `.doc` por `.pdf` pues la "x" sigue viva y resultara presente en la cadena de salida.
Aten en cuenta que la la función `Replace` reemplazará la cadena del primer argumento, cuantas veces aparezca en la cadena original, por la cadena del segundo argumento, por eso mantengo que la respuesta de RobertoLeOr es más elegante.

Comment: me funcionó muy bien el código, pero al momento de publicarlo en el IIS, me sale el siguiente error:

Comment: No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

hace falta alguna configuración para usar esta librería?

Answer (score 0):

De tu declaración

```
FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo("C:\\documento.docx");
```

Tu variable [`wordFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-3.1) tiene varias propiedades; es cuestión uses solo `Name` y le concatenes **pdf**. Es decir:

que

```
object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
```

sea

```
object outputFileName = wordFile.Name + ".pdf";
```